# Brightness, Contrast, etc capabilities not supported under Windows 10 UWP MediaDeviceControl.Capabilities

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10, usb-camera

I am trying to add Brightness, Contrast, etc support to a USB WebCam application I am creating for Windows 10 UWP in C#.  I am using three different USB cameras including a Logitech LogiCam.  What I'm discovering is Brightness, Contrast, even resolutions greater than 640x480 are not supported under Windows 10 UWP.  However, when I examine those capabilities on Android OS they are fully supported.

Are there any overrides or some way to make Windows understand these capabilities are supported by the USB camera?

I've tried examining these capabilities using Android OS with the Saki UVC library and they work just fine.

```
private MediaCapture _mediaCapture;
private MediaDeviceControl _brightnessControl = null;
private MediaDeviceControlCapabilities _brightnessCapabilities = null;
// ...
_brightnessControl = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.Brightness;
if (_brightnessControl != null)
    _brightnessCapabilities = _brightnessControl.Capabilities;
```

[image]

Comment: I see the following from the official doc: Some drivers may require that the camera device preview to be in a running state before it can determine which controls are supported by the VideoDeviceController. If you check whether a certain control is supported by the VideoDeviceController before the preview stream is running, the control may be described as unsupported even though it is supported by the video device. Can you check whether this could be the reason?

Comment: Great suggestion!  Unfortunately, even after the stream is previewing for 10 seconds, brightness, contrast, etc still report as not supported.

Comment: Can you check the driver your are using? If you are using Logitech driver, please make sure that it is not the latest driver. And if you are using in-box driver, the scenario will be different.

Comment: It is the Microsoft device driver created 6/21/2006, version 10.0.17763.404.  When I try to update the driver, Windows 10 tells me its the most recent driver.

Comment: Can you check that whether the Logitech has specific driver for your cameras? Test it first, and if it still reports the same, I will try involve someone in this case to see details(maybe from inbox driver logs).

Comment: Hi Barry.  Thanks.  Logitech does not have a specific driver for this camera.  What I have noticed is if I take the same cameras and try different computers or laptops, it'll work or not work.  In other words, Microsoft's USB Camera Driver alters its behavior based on the hardware its running on.  I used the same USB cameras on each PC I tried.

Comment: Did they use the same version of driver? If they are using the same version then I agree it's actually related to hardware its running on. But I'm not so sure about the difference.

Comment: It was precisely the same version of driver.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is hardware dependent.  I ran this on a new-ish Lenovo laptop and a new-ish Dell laptop.  It worked perfectly fine.